# SQL - why is querying two tables at once causing a 'max execution time' error?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

** Below question edited with requests for more information **

@Bernd Buffen asked "it look like that a index is missing. please post the output from EXPLAIN SELECT game.Name, game.DatabaseID, gameAlt.AlternateName, gameAlt.DatabaseID FROM Game AS game INNER JOIN GameAlternateName AS gameAlt ON game.DatabaseID = gameAlt.DatabaseID WHERE 1 ORDER BY game.DatabaseID LIMIT 100;"

The result of that query is:

```
|id| select_type |  table  | type | rows   | Extra
|1 | SIMPLE      |  game   | ALL  | 137541 | Using temporary / filesort
|1 | SIMPLE      | gameAlt | ALL  | 44292  | Using where / join buffer
```

The other columns (possible_keys / key / key_len and ref) were all NULL - so I omitted them so the table would fit on the page.

****** Original question below *******

Beyond the basics of SQL I have very little experience.

I currently have three tables Game / GameAlternateName / GameImage.

The layout of the tables are:

```
Game Table

| ID | Name       | DatabaseID |
| 1  | Halo       |  10
| 2  | Crysis     |  11
| 3  | Star Fox   |  12
| 4  | Tapper     |  13
| 5  | BioShock   |  14
etc


GameAlternateName Table

| ID | AlternateName       | DatabaseID |
| 1  | Halo CE             |  10
| 2  | Lylat Wars          |  12
| 3  | Lylat Wars          |  12
| 4  | Xingii Huohu        |  12
| 5  | Star Fox 64 v1.0    |  12
etc


GameImage Table

| ID | DatabaseID       | FileName            | Type          |
| 1  | 10               |  936c7c2a2fdb.jpg   | Box - Back    |
| 2  | 10               |  9ffc7c2a2fdb.jpg   | Box - Front   |
| 3  | 10               |  acdc7c2a2fdb.png   | Logo          |
| 4  | 10               |  234c7c2a2fdb.jpg   | Box - Back    |
| 5  | 11               |  93dc7c2a2fdb.png   | Logo          |
etc
```

I would like to query all the tables at once (the tables are very large so just 100 records at a time).

My query of the Game table works well....

```
SELECT Name, DatabaseID
FROM `Game`
WHERE 1
ORDER BY DatabaseID
LIMIT 100
```

So I tried to up the ante and add in the "GameAlternateName" table with this:

```
SELECT game.Name, game.DatabaseID, gameAlt.AlternateName, gameAlt.DatabaseID
FROM `Game` AS game
  INNER JOIN `GameAlternateName` AS gameAlt ON game.DatabaseID = gameAlt.DatabaseID
WHERE 1
ORDER BY game.DatabaseID
LIMIT 100
```

But I just get a max execution error (the query spins for a minute and then times out).

So, I've not even got as far as adding in the third table yet.

I'm wondering if the issue is because the GameAlternateName table (and the GameImage table) have several items associated with one DatabaseID ??

But, I'm very lost here so any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Sample data is great, can you also show us the expected result? (I.e. a [mcve].)

Comment: it look like that a index is missing. please post the output from **EXPLAIN SELECT game.Name, game.DatabaseID, gameAlt.AlternateName, gameAlt.DatabaseID
FROM `Game` AS game
  INNER JOIN `GameAlternateName` AS gameAlt ON game.DatabaseID = gameAlt.DatabaseID
WHERE 1
ORDER BY game.DatabaseID
LIMIT 100;**

Comment: Also, please update the post with the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE Game` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE GameAlternateName`.

Comment: @lemon You can't assume the first 100 rows of each table would satisfy the join.

Comment: Yeah I guess it requires some extra assumptions from the OP for that to happen.

Comment: @WillB. I ran the query SHOW CREATE TABLE Game and it truncates the answer "CREATE TABLE `Game` (
  `id` big... I'm not sure how to show the full result? Thanks

Comment: @BillKarwin you're correct - I'm only getting the first 100 rows as I'm drip feeding the jQuery plugin - DataTables - with the data and the tables are too large to grab in one go. The Game table has 137000 rows. Thanks.

Comment: @jarlh I've tried to cut down the code to it's bare minimum. The actual Game table is called "launchboxdatabase_game" and has 26 fields. I've tried to edit my example down to just show the problem I'm stuck with. An ideal result would be an array that contains all the column headings as keys with the values. This is where I think there may be an issue as, some of the values would have to be arrays themselves (i.e. there are more than one image per game ID and more than one alternate name per game ID) Thanks.

Comment: @JohnT Edit your question to post the results for both the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE ...` queries, assuming you mean that you're trying to reply with the results in a comment and it doesn't allow that many characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah - your query (join) dont use a index.

execute this an test again:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_GameAlternateName ON GameAlternateName(DatabaseID);
```

and also

```
CREATE INDEX idx_DatabaseID ON game(DatabaseID);
```

Comment: That seems to have worked!! Thank you!! For the third table would it just be a case of "CREATE INDEX idx_DatabaseID ON GameImage(DatabaseID)"  ??

Comment: @John T - yes - if you use a join into this table over the GameImage. DatabaseID

Comment: @JohnT I highly recommend doing some research on indexing best-practices, since it is heavily nuanced and dependent on the criteria of your queries (`WHERE` and `JOIN ON ...`), as improper indexing is one of the main causes of slow preforming queries.

Comment: A good site for such research is https://use-the-index-luke.com/. You might also like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: @Bernd Buffen would it be possible to update your answer to explain "what" I'm doing when I run that command? Also, I'm creating my tables via Laravel - how I could alter my Schema::create command to incorporate your suggestions (if possible). Thank you so much :)

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you for the great links. Will work my way through them :)

Comment: @WillB. I see what you mean about it being a nuanced subject! Lots to learn here. Thanks for all your help :-)